# How to adapt code based on .NET 4.0 to make it complatible with .NET 3.5?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, webrtc

I am a newbie with Visual Studio and .NET applications and I have to transform the code of a proyect to make it compatible with .NET 3.5.

Is it feasible? What is the best general aproach to do this?

If someone is interested I want to adapt [WebRTC.Net](https://github.com/radioman/WebRtc.NET) to .NET 3.5.

Comment: Changing the Target Framework in the properties of all the projects to 3.5 and seeing what breaks?

Comment: But considering that the library seems to use at least 5 other libraries, I do feel it won't be possible (but it depends on the target framework of all these libraries)

Comment: @xanatos I was doing that mmm... I am going to check if I can find compatible libraries.

Comment: @xanatos the target framework of all the libraries is 4.0... I spent several hours trying to fix the errors(I even have  to install visual studio 2008), but I think it is not feasible.

Comment: @RenatoSanhueza there is an alternative at https://avspeed.com/ not open source, but I am not sure what your requirements are. works with wpf and winform